# Is it possible to find a list of all smart pointers in Rust Standard Library? If so how?

Tags: rust

I was wondering, is there a way to know the list of all smart pointers in Rust std?

I know `String` and `Vec<T>` are smart pointers, and reading Chp. 15 of the Rust book, I am learning about `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>`, `Ref<T>` and `RefMut<T>`

I was just wondering, is there a place to know all the available smart pointers in Rust's std?

Comment: [in the docs](https://docs.rs/rustc-std-workspace-std/latest/std/), although they are not listed.

Comment: You can peruse the list of [implementors of `Deref`](https://docs.rs/rustc-std-workspace-std/latest/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#implementors).

Comment: If String and Vec are smart pointers, then what is your definition?

Comment: @hkBst: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html, I should imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think an all-encompassing list would be particularly useful since there are lots (especially many which serve more as an implementation detail of another type). If you really want a complete list of everything that's technically a smart pointer, then as eggyal pointed out in a comment on your question you could browse the implementors of `Deref`, but that will probably give you more noise than useful information. I've listed some of the most common and useful ones below:

- [`Box<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) - a unique pointer to an object on the heap. Analogous to C++'s `std::unique_ptr`.
- [`Rc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)/[`Weak<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) - a shared pointer that provides shared ownership of a value on a single thread. This smart pointer cannot be sent between threads safely since it does not use atomic operations to maintain its refcount (the compiler will make sure you don't accidentally do this).
- [`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)/[`Weak<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) - very similar to `Rc` except it uses atomic operations to update its refcount, and thus is thread-safe. Similar to `std::shared_ptr`.
- [`Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html)/[`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html)/[`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html)/[`OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html) et al. - all of these are smart pointers for owning dynamically allocated arrays of items on the heap. Read their documentation for more specific details.
- [`Cow<'a, B>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) - a **c**lone-**o**n-**w**rite smart pointer. Useful for when you have a value that could be borrowed or owned.

The list above isn't the full picture but it will get you very far with most of the code you write.

As you've noted there are other smart pointers like `Ref` and `MutexGuard`. These are returned by types with interior mutability, and usually have some kind of specific behavior on drop, such as releasing a lock or decrementing a refcount. Usually you don't interact with these types as much, but you can read their documentation on an as-needed basis.

There is also [`Pin<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html), but this smart pointer is notoriously hard to understand and really only comes up in conversations about the implementation details of futures and generators. You can read more about it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd classify `Pin<T>` as a smart pointer since it's not owning. It's more like a special kind of reference. It's kind of a blurry line, admittedly.